# How to select column of multidimensional inputs in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a table, where I have checkboxes like:

```
<input id="id_answer[text_singleline][0][1]" type="checkbox" value="1" name="answer[text_singleline][0][1]">
```

where the second index [0] is the row, third index [1] is the column. I need to select all checkboxes in a column, something like this:

```
$('#id_answer\\[text_singleline\\]\\[*\\]\\[0\\]')
```

Is it possible with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the solution of Frédéric does not work with your use case, you can always use the filter method:

```
$('input:[id*=id_answer\\[text_singleline\\]]').filter(function() {
    return /\[.+?\]\[0\]/.test(this.id);
}).each(function() {
    alert(this.id);
});​
```

Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/SmU4z/

More info on the filter method can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: Thanks, I flagged your solution instead of Frederics's (which in this case works too) but this is more general approach.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but it will probably be simpler to use DOM navigation and the [:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector rather than an id selector in your case.

Something like:

```
var checkboxesInFirstColumn = $("#yourTable td:nth-child(1) input:checkbox");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[id="id_answer[text_singleline][0][1]"]')​
```

Use the attribute selector for ID instead of using `#`.

Try this to select all IDs starting with `"id_answer[text_singleline][0]"`:

```
$('input[id^="id_answer[text_singleline][0]"]')​
```

Comment: Yes, but the questioner wants to match a whole column, not a whole row, so a single id selector won't do the trick (thus the properly escaped `\\[*\\]` selector fragment in the question).